# Cannot sign-in my Ionic app with Google

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm an ionic noob. I'm trying to login in to my app via social media apis.

I first followed this tutorial app: https://github.com/chanusukarno/Angular-Ionic-OAuth

This worked fine in browser but didn't work once installed in phone. I tried the following plugins:

1) [phonegap-facebook-plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin) (which works fine in browser)

2) [EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus.git) (This one gave me build errors)
    So after reading [this issue about EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus/issues/64) I went on and installed        `nl.x-services.plugins.googleplus`

I have installed the plugin nl.x-services.plugins.googleplus but I get the error "**Class not found**" @ the line where I call `window.plugins.googleplus.login`

Comment: It does't answer your question, but may I sugest you use the Nick Raboy's plugin https://github.com/nraboy/ng-cordova-oauth It's really great. Additionally, you should take a look on his blog too. It's a great resource for starters: blog.nraboy.com/

Comment: I would only use the ng-cordova plugins. They work the best and are easy to use. http://ngcordova.com/

Comment: satellizer is also a great library to authenticate on various oauth based networks

Comment: I have tried ngcordova and phonegap plugins both. I'm pretty sure I'm missing something.

Comment: Are you sure you have created and used correct API keys?

Comment: @Aster I have generated a hashkey with keeytool command and updated it in the developer console. The fact that the first plugin works with ionic serve means I have done that step right. Though I could post a picture or edit my question if that explains things better..